# Pivot table of summations from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have problems extracting data from these tables. I have a statistics system where numbers are entered for employees every some days in the month - for the sake of example here are only two months but it will be a full year. I tried a join but I received doubled results + some employee can work on more accounts while others could work on only one...

**employees**:

```
+----+-------------+--+
| ID |    Name     |  |
+----+-------------+--+
|  1 | John Doe    |  |
|  2 | Helen Price |  |
|  3 | John Price  |  |
+----+-------------+--+
```

**Account**

```
+----+---------+--+
| ID |  Name   |  |
+----+---------+--+
|  1 | fisher  |  |
|  2 | fisher1 |  |
+----+---------+--+
```

**January**

```
+----+-------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| ID |    Employee | Account | firstday | seconday | thirdday |
+----+-------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 | John Doe    | fisher  |        2 |        4 |        6 | 
|  2 | Helen Price | fisher  |        1 |        1 |        1 | 
|  3 | John Price  | fisher1 |        1 |        2 |        1 | 
|  4 | John Price  | fisher  |        1 |        1 |        1 | 
+----+-------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

**February**

```
+----+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| ID |    Employee | Account | fourthday | eightday | secondday | 
+----+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | John Doe    | fisher  |         1 |        4 |         6 |  
|  2 | Helen Price | fisher  |         1 |        1 |         2 |  
|  3 | John Price  | fisher1 |         1 |        2 |         1 |   
|  4 | John Price  | fisher  |         1 |        1 |         1 |    
+----+-------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

My question is how can I write a query with the following result:

```
   +----+-------------+---------+-----------------+------------------+--------+--+
| ID |  Employee   | Account | January(totals) | February(totals) | Totals |  |
+----+-------------+---------+-----------------+------------------+--------+--+
|  1 | John Doe    | fisher  |              12 |               11 |     23 |  |
|  2 | Helen Price | fisher  |               3 |                4 |      7 |  |
|  3 | John Price  | fisher  |               3 |                3 |      6 |  |
+----+-------------+---------+-----------------+------------------+--------+--+
```

Comment: Your design is simply horrible, make a table ID,emploee_ID,, Aaccount_ID, datetime, Hours. So you can make a simple querys to get minthly hours and total, but for your desire to write the monthname as columnname, you can use mysq statements or/and stored procedure

Comment: Despite being a poor schema structure, the only thing that really needs clarification is, how are the Accounts expected to be filtered to achieve the desired results? Everything else seems straight-forward with a clear problem of *doubled results* and desired results of the summation of the individual join tables, with sample data.

Comment: Sorry, I am learning now MySql - the design may be horrible - that's why I want to learn how to do things better and get some advice from here....employees and account tables have one to many relationships defined with each month table...also I added foreign check constraints in each month table that points to employees and account tables - "name" field in each of the two tables is defined as primary key. Thank a lot for your help - I am newbie in mysql query programming and I never knew about " pivot tables"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting is a pivot-table of aggregate results from the different `JOIN` tables.
There are a couple of approaches, but one approach is using `LEFT JOIN` with aggregate subqueries to total your monthly results by each employee and account.

In your sample data, there is no correlation of `Employee` to `Account` outside of your Month tables. So the association needs to be created by using another subquery to create the correlation to join the monthly tables on. This will cause an association for every employee and every account unless a many-to-many table is created to create the association.

Lastly since your sample data is only showing a single Account (`fisher`), you would need to filter it somehow, which was not specified clearly in your question, so I added it in to the `WHERE` criteria.

### Example: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dfy1peFsycFZgipwsjYvzC/0)

```sql
SELECT
  e.ID,
  e.Name AS Employee,
  e.Account,
  COALESCE(janurary_totals.total, 0) AS `January(totals)`,
  COALESCE(february_totals.total, 0) AS `February(totals)`,
  COALESCE(janurary_totals.total, 0) + COALESCE(february_totals.total, 0) AS Totals
FROM (
   SELECT e1.ID, e1.Name, a1.Name AS Account
   FROM employees AS e1
   LEFT JOIN Account AS a1
   ON a1.ID IS NOT NULL
) AS e
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
       Employee,
       Account,
       SUM(firstday) + SUM(seconday) + SUM(thirdday) AS total
   FROM January
   GROUP BY Employee, Account
) AS janurary_totals
ON janurary_totals.Employee = e.Name
AND janurary_totals.Account = e.Account
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
       Employee,
       Account,
       SUM(fourthday) + SUM(eightday) + SUM(secondday) AS total
   FROM February
   GROUP BY Employee, Account
) AS february_totals
ON february_totals.Employee = e.Name
AND february_totals.Account = e.Account
WHERE e.Account = 'fisher'
```

**Result**

```
| ID  | Employee    | Account | January(totals) | February(totals) | Totals |
| --- | ----------- | ------- | --------------- | ---------------- | ------ |
| 1   | John Doe    | fisher  | 12              | 11               | 23     |
| 2   | Helen Price | fisher  | 3               | 4                | 7      |
| 3   | John Price  | fisher  | 3               | 3                | 6      |
```

---

You could greatly simplify things, by refactoring the individual month tables into a single `employee_entry` table with an `employee_id`, `account_id`, `amount` and `DATE` columns, that you could use to query against to create the pivot-table. As it stands currently, there is no means of determining which year the values are recorded, which will cause confusion on subsequent year totals.

The single entry table would allow you to create a pivot-table using conditional aggregates.

```
SUM(CASE MONTH(date_column) WHEN # THEN amount_column ELSE 0 END) AS MonthTotal
```

Allowing you to filter and group the results as desired.

### Example: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jEZirpWARwMgUzVHPUitkm/2)

```sql
SELECT
e.`Name` AS Employee,
a.`Name` AS Account,
m.`Year`,
m.`January(totals)`,
m.`February(totals)`,
m.`Totals`
FROM (
    SELECT
        ee.employee_id,
        ee.account_id,
        YEAR(ee.`datetime`) AS `Year`,
        SUM(CASE MONTH(ee.datetime) WHEN 1 THEN ee.amount ELSE 0 END) AS `January(totals)`,
        SUM(CASE MONTH(ee.datetime) WHEN 2 THEN ee.amount ELSE 0 END) AS `February(totals)`,
        SUM(ee.amount) AS `Totals`
    FROM employee_entry AS ee
    GROUP BY ee.employee_id, ee.account_id, `Year`
) AS m
LEFT JOIN employees AS e
ON e.ID = m.employee_id
LEFT JOIN Account AS a
ON a.ID = m.account_id
```

**Result**

```
| Employee    | Account | Year | January(totals) | February(totals) | Totals |
| ----------- | ------- | ---- | --------------- | ---------------- | ------ |
| Helen Price | fisher  | 2020 | 3               | 4                | 7      |
| John Doe    | fisher  | 2020 | 12              | 11               | 23     |
| John Price  | fisher  | 2020 | 3               | 3                | 6      |
| John Price  | fisher1 | 2020 | 4               | 4                | 8      |
```

---

To perform the conversion, you create the `employee_entry` table, and insert your individual monthly tables into it, by specifying a date for each of the `day` columns.

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee_entry (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` INTEGER,
  `account_id` INTEGER,
  `amount` INTEGER,
  `datetime` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO employee_entry
  (`employee_id`, `account_id`, `amount`, `datetime`)
  (
    SELECT e.ID, a.ID, j.firstday, '2020-01-01' 
    FROM `January` AS j
    LEFT JOIN employees AS e
    ON j.Employee = e.Name
    LEFT JOIN Account  AS a
    ON j.Account = a.Name
  )
  UNION
  (
    SELECT e.ID, a.ID, j.seconday, '2020-01-02' 
    FROM `January` AS j
    LEFT JOIN employees AS e
    ON j.Employee = e.Name
    LEFT JOIN Account  AS a
    ON j.Account = a.Name
  )
  UNION
  (
    SELECT e.ID, a.ID, j.thirdday, '2020-01-03' 
    FROM `January` AS j
    LEFT JOIN employees AS e
    ON j.Employee = e.Name
    LEFT JOIN Account  AS a
    ON j.Account = a.Name
  )
  UNION
  (
    SELECT e.ID, a.ID, f.fourthday, '2020-02-04' 
    FROM `February` AS f
    LEFT JOIN employees AS e
    ON f.Employee = e.Name
    LEFT JOIN Account  AS a
    ON f.Account = a.Name
  )
  UNION
  (
    SELECT e.ID, a.ID, f.eightday, '2020-02-08' 
    FROM `February` AS f
    LEFT JOIN employees AS e
    ON f.Employee = e.Name
    LEFT JOIN Account  AS a
    ON f.Account = a.Name
  )
  UNION
  (
    SELECT e.ID, a.ID, f.secondday, '2020-02-02' 
    FROM `February` AS f
    LEFT JOIN employees AS e
    ON f.Employee = e.Name
    LEFT JOIN Account  AS a
    ON f.Account = a.Name
  );
```